# What will be the output of this one?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

What will be output of the code:

```
def gfg(x,l=[]):
       for i in range(x):
          l.append(i*i)
       print(l)
```

What is the output of following function calls-

gfg(3,[3,2,1])

gfg(3)

Answer (score 1):

First of all welcome to stackoverflow! For the following code it's probably best to just try to run your code in a python shell and see the output. But I can provide some explanation as to why you get the output that you do.
Your code was as follows:

```
def gfg(x, l=[]):
    for i in range(x):
        l.append(i*i)
    print(l)
```

And we are trying to run this function on the following input:
gfg(3, [3,2,1]) and gfg(3).

The output that we get is as follows:
gfg(3, [3,2,1]) = [3,2,1,0,1,4]
gfg(3) = [0,1,4]

This is because python uses something called default arguments that are used when we do not pass in the required number of arguments into a function. So in the first case when we print out l we get that 0,1,4 is appended onto the end of the existing parameter l that is passed into the function ([3,2,1]. And when we do not pass in an argument for l the output is just the list [0,1,4].